# How to solve expectation / first moment of Gaussian Integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I solve the following integral?

$E[I] = \int_{I=0}^\infty I \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{(\mu-f-I)^2}{2\sigma^2}) dI$

The result is supposed to be:

$\sigma[\frac{\mu - f}{\sigma}\Phi(\frac{\mu - f}{\sigma}) + \phi(\frac{\mu - f}{\sigma})]$, where $\Phi(.)$ and $\phi(.)$ are the Gaussian probability density function and the cumulative probability function.

I tried integration by parts and variable substitution like done [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html).

But neither approach gets me the solution. I would like to know the steps to get to the result.

This whole thing is from Bayesian Optimisation, like here: p.23 E. Brochu, PhD Thesis 2010: Interactive Bayesian Optimization, https://circle.ubc.ca/bitstream/handle/2429/30519/ubc_2011_spring_brochu_eric.pdf?sequence=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the change of variable $\sigma x=\mu-f-I$ and the shorthand $\alpha=(\mu-f)/\sigma$, one sees that the integral to be computed is
$$
J=\int_{-\infty}^\alpha\sigma\cdot(\alpha-x)\cdot\varphi(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
The last piece of information you might need to conclude is that, since $x\varphi(x)=-\varphi'(x)$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\alpha(-x)\cdot\varphi(x)\mathrm dx=\varphi(\alpha).
$$